# PUT and PATCH for Content Builder API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

i have pushed a content using REST API in content Builder, now i want to update the content that is pushed, im trying to use PUT and PATCH for the same but its giving 500 internal server error. Below is the payload that im trying to pass

EndPoint URL that i'm using for PUT/PATCH  is [`https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/{20843}`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm)

```
{
  "customerKey":"f62c1eee-faa0-4059-8644-d99b139dc371",     
  "name": "emailtest_8",
    "views": {
    "html": {
      "content": "<!DOCTYPE html><body>This is a simple html paste email.</body></html>"
    }
    },
    "assetType": {
    "name": "htmlemail",
    "id": 208
   }
}
```

I have tried using POSTMAN rest client to test but still it says

> 500 internal server error.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Salesforce doesn't support the PATCH method for HttpRequests.... so there's a rabbit hole you can avoid going down.

Comment: Incorrect - SFMC does allow the PATCH method.

Comment: on your endpoint, remove the curly brackets {} and leave just the ID number

Comment: @Gortonington thanks mate, PATCH is working now. Is PUT method supported for httprequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoint does not need the curly brackets around it.  Remove {} from around your ID number and your call should work perfectly.

SFMC does allow the following:

1. POST
2. GET
3. PUT
4. PATCH
5. DELETE

This is shown in the [REST API reference section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm) of the help docs